# Use Keras (Tensorflow backend) with mobile GPU (laptop)

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

If I only use the Tensorflow code, the GPU usage rate is more than 80% and temperature rises very much. But if I use Kers, the usage rate drops to 15%. Also, using Keras does not reach the maximum clock of the GPU.

I tried with 980m, 1070 (laptop) and 960m, but the same result was obtained. ANN and CNN all have the same result.

Why is my GPU utilisation so low when using Kers on a mobile (laptop) GPU? What can I do to ensure I am getting maximum performance when using Keras on a laptop?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to solve the problem of not getting the maximum performance when using a keras in a laptop.

Comment: That depends on a looot of factors, unfortunately. Is your laptop windows or linux? Which version? How did you install tensorflow? Pip? Anaconda conda? Anaconda pip? Did you compile it yourself? How did you install keras? (I noticed that the anaconda version of keras ignores tensorflow-gpu and installs its own regular tensorflow. The pip version of keras uses the tensorflow-gpu. But that was on Ubuntu 16.04).  Unfortunately there are sooo many vars that it's not simple at all to answer this question.

Comment: anaconda 4.4.0 / window 10 / python 3.5 / i installed tensorflow with anaconda conda / i installed keras with git

Comment: I apologize for not filling in the question in detail.

Comment: What if you uninstall keras and reinsall it with pip in the same environment you installed tensorflow gpu??? (Please check that you don't have two tensorflows, one regulas and one gpu, you should have only the gpu one)

Comment: The problem was solved to some extent by adjusting the batch size in Keras. (I only have the gpu version.) Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe upgrade to Tensorflow 1.3. In TF 1.3 Keras is already included and there is no need to additionaly install keras.

In order to use the keras version included in TF do the following:
Use for example

```
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.models import Model
```

or

```
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Dropout
```

instead of

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Dropout
```

Maybe that solves the problem!

Comment: i think some of the commands used by Keras seem to cause bottlenecks. The problem was resolved somewhat by adjusting the batch size. Thank you very much for your help.